# Error Converting DataType varchar to Numeric

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

In my stored procedure, I get data from three tables but got this error:

> *Error Converting Data Type varchar to Numeric.*

I think problem is in :-

```
'NULL' AS DATE (in 1st query of this SP)------(1)
CONVERT(VARCHAR, tbl_IPD.ipd_doa, 103) AS DATE (in 2nd query of this SP)-----(2)
```

My question is: how to convert (1) line to varchar

```
SELECT 
   tbl_CompanyProfile.Company_Name, tbl_CompanyProfile.Company_Address, 
   tbl_CompanyProfile.Company_ContactNo, tbl_CompanyProfile.Company_Email, 
   tbl_CompanyProfile.Company_Website, 
   'NULL' AS NAME, 'NULL' AS DATE,
   'NULL' AS AMOUNT, 'NULL' AS DEPARTMENT, 
   0 AS Age, @from AS StartDate, @to AS EndDate
FROM 
   tbl_CompanyProfile

UNION ALL

SELECT   
   '--', '--',
   '--', '--', '--', 
   tbl_IPD.ipd_pfname + ' ' + tbl_IPD.ipd_plname AS NAME, 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR, tbl_IPD.ipd_doa, 103) AS DATE, 
   ISNULL(SUM(tbl_fee.fee_amount), 0) AS AMOUNT, 
   tblDepartment.DeptName AS DEPARTMENT, tbl_IPD.ipd_age AS Age,  
   @from AS StartDate, @to AS EndDate
FROM            
   tbl_fee 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   tbl_IPD ON tbl_fee.ipd_id = tbl_IPD.ipd_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   tblDepartment ON tbl_IPD.ipd_dpt = tblDepartment.DeptId 
WHERE        
   (tbl_IPD.ipd_doa BETWEEN @from AND @to)
GROUP BY 
    tbl_IPD.ipd_pfname, tbl_IPD.ipd_plname, tbl_IPD.ipd_doa, tblDepartment.DeptName, tbl_IPD.ipd_age
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is actually in the `AMOUNT` column - you are selecting `NULL` (character string) in the first query and trying to join it to a numeric result in the second query. If you want to use an actual `NULL` value in the union just take the apostrophes off of the `NULL` references.

Comment: on showing on report show null values but we want to show only tbl_companyprofile field..please tell how to hide all field on report in same above store procedure

Comment: I don't understand the question - perhaps you should post a new question with a better explanation of the desired results.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to return a `NULL` value you should remove quotes on `'NULL'`, otherwise you're returning a `varchar` and that's not what you're aprobably trying to do.

If my assumption is correct, this is how your query should looks like.

```
...NULL AS NAME, NULL AS DATE, NULL AS AMOUNT, NULL AS DEPARTMENT,...
```